# Is there a way to pass parameter to a replaceable/redeclared component?

Tags: modelica

This question is related to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298679/modelica-how-to-use-replaceable-components).

I have some submodels that are interchangeable and I use the replaceable/redeclare mechanism to include them in a model (e.g. submodels of different type of heat-exchangers in a cooling loop model).

I would like to "link" some parameters of the main model (let's say the pipes' length and diameter) to the corresponding parameters of the submodule. This is usually done when defining a model instance (i.e. in the `replaceable` line), but how can this link be applied also when the componenet is redeclared? Expecially if `choicesAllMatching` is used?

Here is "my" model (thanks to helpers in the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298679/modelica-how-to-use-replaceable-components)):

```
package Test
  // Original definition of Component 1 and 2 in the external library
  // COMP1 (COMP2) has a parameter p1 (p2) defined with a default value
  package ReadOnlyLibrary
    model COMP1
      parameter Real p1=1 "";
      Real v "";
    equation 
      v=p1*time;
    end COMP1;

    model COMP2
      parameter Real p2=1 "";
      Real v "";
    equation 
      v=p2*time;
    end COMP2;
  end ReadOnlyLibrary;

  // Interface and variants with modified default values
  partial model Call_Interface
    parameter Real pp = 10; // New parameter definition to have the same name for all variants
    Real v "";
  end Call_Interface;

  // Both Call1 and Call2 parameters (p1 and p2) are linked to pp
  model Call1 "Default"
    extends Call_Interface;
    extends ReadOnlyLibrary.COMP1(p1=pp);
  end Call1;

  model Call2 "Variant"
    extends Call_Interface;
    extends ReadOnlyLibrary.COMP2(p2=pp);
  end Call2;

  // Main module (system)
  model Main
    parameter Real pm=100 "";
    parameter Real pp0=1 ""; //Actual parameter value to be used by submodules for this application -> pp
    Real vm "";

    replaceable Test.Call1 OBJ(pp=pp0) constrainedby Test.Call_Interface annotation (choicesAllMatching); //For default definition, pp, and finally p1, are linked to pp0. But when OBJ is redeclarated, the link is lost and p1/p2 gets its default value.

  equation 
    vm = OBJ.v+pm;
  end Main;

  // Application model, using the main model
  model App
    Main main;
  end App;
end Test;
```

I could add all possible redeclarations in the annotation by writing for example `choice(redeclare Test.Call2 OBJ(pp=pp0))` instead of using `choiceAllMatching` but that may become tedius and error prone when many submodules are interchangeables (it would be easier and safer to write the "link" just once). 
I tried by adding a generic `OBJ.pp = pp0` in Main model parameter section, but this is not accepted. What is the proper way of doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to write the modifiers to the constraining class:

```
replaceable Test.Call1 OBJ constrainedby Test.Call_Interface(pp=pp0) 
    annotation (choicesAllMatching);
```

Comment: @Songio Other related examples here: http://book.xogeny.com/components/architectures/sensor_comparison_ad/#variations